# QToolBar does not show text next to icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class ConfigureBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.addAction(QtWidgets.QIcon("some_icon.png"), "Hi")
        self.addSeparator()
        self.addAction(QIcon("some_icon.png"), "Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = ConfigureBar()

    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

But for some reason, the displayed widget does not have a text (Hi, Hello), only the icon. I tried to find some answer but I can't seem to get the keyword right. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`toolButtonStyle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#toolButtonStyle-prop) property indicates the style of how the QToolButtons are shown, and by default it is `Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly`, so only show the icon, if you want to show the text you have to use `Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon` or `Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ConfigureBar(QtWidgets.QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        # or
        # self.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)

        self.addAction(QtGui.QIcon("some_icon.png"), "Hi")
        self.addSeparator()
        self.addAction(QtGui.QIcon("some_icon.png"), "Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    toolbar = ConfigureBar()

    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    w.addToolBar(toolbar)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! You really know a lot huh. So what is the best way to get these information, other than coming here?